# Testing Pull Subscription in Java EWS API using PowerMockito

Tags: java, mocking, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I have a function that processes events obtained by a `PullSubscription` to Microsoft Exchange.

```
public void processEvents(ExchangeService service, PullSubscription subscription)
            throws Exception {
    GetEventsResults events = subscription.getEvents();
    // Loop through all item-related events.
    for (ItemEvent itemEvent : events.getItemEvents()) {
        if (itemEvent.getEventType() == EventType.NewMail) {
            EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, itemEvent.getItemId());
            EmailParser emailParser = new EmailParser();
            emailParser.parse(message, service);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to test it using PowerMockito because `ExchangeService` is a final class.
So I have mocked `ExchangeService` and `PullSubscription` as follows:

```
ExchangeService serviceMock = PowerMockito.mock(ExchangeService.class);
PullSubscription subscriptionMock = PowerMockito.mock(PullSubscription.class);

@Test
public void startPullNotification() throws Exception {
    ProcessEmails pr = new ProcessEmails("config.properties");
    pr.startPullNotification(serviceMock);
}
```

When I'm trying to test it using the following code it throws a `NullPointerException` because `subscription.getEvents()` returns `null` (i.e. the `subscriptionMock` has no events in it).

I tried stubbing it by mocking the `eventResults` that has to be returned:

```
when(subscriptionMock.getEvents()).thenReturn(eventResultsMock);
```

It doesn't work since the `getEvents()` is not called in the test function. I wanted to know how to test this function?

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi

**Solution:**

I had to mock every object being created in the function.
Also, I had to add the following above the class declaration.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ClassBeingTested.class })
```